# How to refer to a button that's been clicked and not by its id

Tags: javascript

I want to write javascript code which will recognize which button has been clicked and change its label. There are multiple buttons on the web page so there is no possibility of referring to it by its id. It is identified only by the fact that it has been clicked. 
I saw one discussion on stack overflow that suggested writing

```
<input type = "button" value = " " id ="3" onclick="click(event)">
```

on the web page, and then defining *click* as a function with one argument, let's call it 
ev. Then I referred to it (inside the function) by

```
var button = ev.target;
```

and then tried to change the value of button. It didn't work. I just want a button's label to change when I click it without referring to it by id (I can't tell what it's id is since it's just the button that was clicked amongst many).
Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: Please show the js you have tried which did not work

Comment: is jQuery avalilable on your site?

Comment: pass another parameter

Comment: You should be using `var button = this;`

Comment: I tried to duplicate your issue and found that using the function name `click` doesn't work.  It seems you'll need to name it something else to get the `onClick` event to fire.  Then follow Andy's and adeneo's  advice.

Comment: @David - that's right, `click` is reserved for an event, the click event.

Comment: "is jQuery available?" - priceless.

Answer (score 5):

```
onclick="clickMe(this)">
```

This will pass a reference to the element clicked on, then you can get/set anything that you normally can from the element e.g:

```
function clickMe(el) {
  el.value = "Hi"; // set
  alert(el.value); // get
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8C3EN/1/)

Note: calling a function `click()` is not allowed as it is a reserved keyword (just like you wouldn't have a function called `function()`, which is why I made it `clickMe()`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `this` keyword as a parameter, and use a data attribute to hold the new value :

html :

```
<input type="button" value=" " id="a3" data-value="test" onclick="func(this)">
```

js

```
function func(elem) {
    elem.value = elem.getAttribute('data-value');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hJk6b/)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is set to the button that is clicked by the browser:

```
<input type=button onclick=clickhandler>
<script>
function clickhandler() {
    this.value = "foo";    // button’s label is now foo
    console.log(this.id);  // will print the button’s id
}
</script>
```